# Laravel 5.4 query check if value exists between the keys/values of an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and this is my use case:

I have a list of `Lessons`, every `Lesson` is associated with a specific `User` and has a `date`, `star_at` and `end_at` fields. In the form that allows me to add/edit `Lessons` I need to do a validation check ( we choose the date, start and end 
 in the form ):
- The new `Lesson` shouldn't be in the time range (`start_at` -> `end_at`) of another Lesson during the selected `date`.

So I did a query to retrieve all the `Lessons` ( as an array of key(start_at) & value(end_at) ) of the current `User` where `date` = the selected date in the form.

Now I need to check if the `start_at` value that we've chosen in the form exists in the time range of any of the retrieved `Lessons` array records. and maybe then display the error ( There is already a Lesson in this time range at this date ).

Please help, it can be a bit unclear, but I can explain further if you need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you add new Lesson then it shouldn't be in range of other Lesson of that specific user ? Am I right ?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the question, the below code should do the trick. Change the model and field names based on your application.

```
protected function store()
{
    $input = request()->all();

    $lessons = Lesson::whereDate('date', Carbon::parse($input['date']))
        ->where('start_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($input['start_at']))
        ->where('end_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($input['start_at']))
        ->count();

    if ($lessons) {
        // lesson in exists on this date in the given time frame.
        // handle error
    }

    Lesson::create($input);

    // handle success
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the way.